# Is there any possibilty to build an application that runs virtually without being installed on the mobile phone?

Tags: android, mobile, kaios

I wanna build an application that runs virtually on a mobile phone which doesn't need to be installed. I want it such a way that I can run and access that virtual application with some sort of link or something.
Is there any possibility to build such applications?
If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check out [Instant Apps](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant).

Comment: That's useful but that is for increasing the engagement of your app but in my case, I want to build an application that could run virtually without the help of play store.

Comment: Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: I haven't seen such thing, lets see if someone else replies.